# How to check remaining space in storage device EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, disk

I've connected to amazon Ec2 instance through putty. 
How can I check the remaining space in instance?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

After you login using putty, enter command:

```
$ df -h
```

df - Disk filesystem
-h is human readable format

Answer (score 58):

After you login using putty, enter command:

```
$ df -hT /dev/xvda1
```

Comment: This is a more useful answer than the accepted one.

Comment: the question is how do I check what is inside xvda1 volume

Answer (score 1):

**df - Disk Filesystem**

- **-h is human readable format**

  df -f

[image]

- **-i is inode format**

  df -i

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the kinds of storage volumes you have mounted, `df -h` can often hang or take a very long time to run. If this happens, you can check storage on your EBS volumes by running `df` with the `-l, --local` argument:

```
df -hl
```

The `--local` argument limits it to local file systems (which include EBS volumes) so it runs much more quickly, while the `-h` argument makes it print sizes in a human readable format

```
-h, --human-readable  print sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)
-l, --local           limit listing to local file systems
```